# Modal se cierra automáticamente después de abrirse

Tags: javascript, html5, django, modal, material-design-lite

Tengo un problema con un Modal el cual se cierra automáticamente una vez abres haces click en el botón para abrirlo tal cual se muestra en el siguiente vídeo de unos segundos de duración

https://youtu.be/X0Df4mJZQ80

mi código es el siguiente:

```
{% extends "base/base.html" %}

{% block navbar %}
    <nav class="mdl-navigation">
        <a id="btn_add" class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">add</i>Registrar</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">delete</i>Eliminar</a>
        <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">cached</i>Act. Pag.</a>
    </nav>
{% endblock navbar %}

{% block content %}

<style>
    body {
        'padding-top: 20px;
        'padding-left: 20px;

    }

    .mdl-dialog {
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0 9px 46px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 11px 15px -7px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12), 0 24px 38px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        width: 50%;
        height: 70%;
        position:absolute;
        height: fit-content;
    }
    .mdl-dialog::backdrop{
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    }
    .mdl-dialog__title {
        padding: 24px 24px 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: 2.5rem; 
    }
    .mdl-dialog__content{
        overflow-y: auto;
        'overflow:auto;
        max-height: 100%;
    }
    .mdl-dialog__actions {
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 24px;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap; }
        .mdl-dialog__actions > * {
        margin-right: 8px;
        height: 36px; 
    }
    .mdl-dialog__actions > *:first-child {
        margin-right: 0;
        'position: fixed;
    }
    .mdl-dialog__actions--full-width {
        padding: 0 0 8px 0; 
    }
    .mdl-dialog__actions--full-width > * {
        height: 100%;
        -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
        -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
        flex: 0 0 100%;
        padding-right: 16px;
        margin-right: 0;
        text-align: right; 
    }
    .mdl-dialog__content {
        padding: 20px 24px 24px 24px;
        color: rgba(0,0,0, 0.54); 
    }
    .mdl-tabs__tab-bar{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>

<div class="mdl-grid">
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
    <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--10-col">
        <ul class="demo-list-two mdl-list">
            {% for cotizacion in cotizaciones %}

                <li class="mdl-list__item mdl-list__item--two-line">
                    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
                        <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">description</i>
                        <span>{{ cotizacion.folio}} ({{ cotizacion.estatus}})</span>
                        <span class="mdl-list__item-sub-title">
                            <a id="" class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">person_outline</i>{{ cotizacion.cliente }}</a>
                            <a id="" class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">attach_money</i>{{ cotizacion.tipo_moneda }}</a>
                        </span>
                    </span>
                    <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content mdl-list__item--two-line">
                        <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect" href="#"><i id="edit_quote" class="material-icons">mode_edit</i>Editar</a>
                        <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-ripple-effect" href="#"><i id="delete_quote" class="material-icons">delete</i>Eliminar</a>
                    </span>
                </li>

            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
</div>

<!-- Segundo dialog para mostrar despues del primero -->
<dialog class="mdl-dialog" id="modal-language">
    <h7 class="mdl-dialog__title">Selecciona un idioma</h7>
    <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
        <form method="POST">
            <div class="mdl-tabs mdl-js-tabs mdl-js-ripple-effect">
                <p>El idioma que selecciones sera utilizado para la cotizacion, es importante elegir el idioma correcto para tus cilentes</p>
            </div>
            <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
                <button style="background:#dedfe0;width:100%;text-align:center" id="btn_es" type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-list__item-primary-action"><i class="material-icons"></i>Español</button>
                <button style="background:#dedfe0;width:100%;text-align:center" id="btn_en" type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-list__item-primary-action"><i class="material-icons"></i>Ingles</button>
                <button style="background:#dedfe0;width:100%;text-align:center" id="btn_cancel" type="button" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-list__item-primary-action"><i class="material-icons">close</i>Cancelar</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</dialog>

<script type="text/javascript">

</script>
{% endblock content %}
```

Este es mi archivo base del cual hereda todo el archivo anterior:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
        <!--Import Roboto fonts -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700" type="text/css">
        <!--Import materialize.css
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://storage.googleapis.com/code.getmdl.io/1.0.6/material.indigo-pink.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>
        -->

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/material.min.css' %}"  media="screen,projection"/>

        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.css" media="screen,projection"/>

        <style>
            .demo-layout-waterfall .mdl-layout__header-row .mdl-navigation__link:last-of-type  {
                padding-right: 0;
            }

            /* codigo CSS para dar estilo a la carta */
            .mdl-card__actions {
                display: flex;
                box-sizing:border-box;
                align-items: center;
            }
            .mdl-card__actions > .mdl-button--icon {
                margin-right: 3px;
                margin-left: 3px;
            }
            .errorlist{
                color: red;
            }
            .mdl-textfield{
                width: 100%;
            }
            .mdl-textfield__label{
                color: darkgrey;
            }
            .mdl-button--floating-action {
                bottom:25px;
                margin-bottom:25px;
                padding-top:24px;
                position:fixed;
                right:24px;
                z-index:998;
            }


            body {
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: inline-block;
            }

            /* Add Animation */
            @-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
                from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
                to {top:0; opacity:1}
            }

            @keyframes animatetop {
                from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
                to {top:0; opacity:1}
            }

            /* The Close Button */
            .close {
                color: white;
                float: right;
                font-size: 28px;
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .close:hover,
            .close:focus {
                color: #000;
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .modal-header {
                padding: 2px 16px;
                background-color: #f9e061;
                color: white;
            }

            .modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

            .modal-footer {
                padding: 2px 16px;
                background-color: #f9e061;
                color: white;
            }
        </style>

        <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
        <title>oaSys</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="demo-layout-waterfall mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
        <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--waterfall">
          <!-- Top row, always visible -->
          <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <!-- Title -->
            <span class="mdl-layout-title">
                {% block titleApp %}
                    OasisSystem | {{ user.first_name }} {{ user.last_name }} ({{ user.username }})
                {% endblock titleApp %}
            </span>
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--expandable
                        mdl-textfield--floating-label mdl-textfield--align-right">
              <label class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon"
                      for="waterfall-exp">
                <i class="material-icons">search</i>
              </label>
              <div class="mdl-textfield__expandable-holder">
                <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" name="sample" id="waterfall-exp">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Bottom row, not visible on scroll -->
          <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
            <div class="mdl-layout-spacer"></div>
            <!-- Navigation -->
            {% block navbar %}
              <nav class="mdl-navigation">
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">add</i>Registrar</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">delete</i>Eliminar</a>
                <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">cached</i>Act. Pag.</a>
              </nav>
            {% endblock navbar %}
          </div>
        </header>
        <div class="mdl-layout__drawer">
          <span class="mdl-layout-title">OasiSystem</span>
          <nav class="mdl-navigation">
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">event_note</i>cotizaciones</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">assignment</i>Captura</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">description</i>Analisis</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="{% url 'sucursal' %}"><i class="material-icons">business</i>Sucursales</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="{% url 'cliente' %}"><i class="material-icons">business_center</i>Clientes</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href="{% url 'empleado' %}"><i class="material-icons">group</i>Empleados</a>
            <a class="mdl-navigation__link" href=""><i class="material-icons">person</i>Usuarios</a>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <main class="mdl-layout__content">
          <div class="page-content">

            {% block content %}

            {% endblock content %}

          </div>
        </main>
      </div>

    <!-- JavaScript at end of body for optimized loading -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_1_7_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dialog-polyfill/0.4.2/dialog-polyfill.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/material.min.js' %}"></script>
    <!-- 
    <script src="{% static 'js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js' %}"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jQuery_3_3_1 = $.noConflict(true);
    </script>
    -->

    <script>
        $( function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
        } );
        /*
        $(function() {
            $( ".datepicker" ).datepicker({
                format: "dd/mm/yyy",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                yearRange: "1900:" + (new Date()).getFullYear(),
                // You can put more options here.
            });
        });
        */

            /* funciones del modal */
    (function() {
            'use strict';
            var dialog = document.querySelector('#modal-language');
            var addButton = document.querySelector('#btn_add');
            var cancelButton = dialog.querySelector('#btn_cancel');
            var esButton = dialog.querySelector('#btn_es');
            var enButton = document.querySelector('#btn_en');
            if (! dialog.showModal) {
                dialogPolyfill.registerDialog(dialog);
            }
            var closeClickHandler = function(event) {
                dialog.close();
            };
            var showClickHandler = function(event) {
                dialog.showModal();
            };
            addButton.addEventListener('click', showClickHandler);
            cancelButton.addEventListener('click', closeClickHandler);
            esButton.addEventListener('click', closeClickHandler);
            enButton.addEventListener('click', closeClickHandler);
        }());
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Espero puedan ayudarme se los agradecería mucho, las librerías que estoy usando son Material Design Lite, no se si eso tenga algo que ver pero estoy seguro que no ya que estoy tratando de insertar el siguiente fragmento de código en esta sección

https://codepen.io/fer626/pen/VxBzvY

Les agradezco por anticipado su ayuda

Comment: De seguro tienes un problema en el evento, podrías probar disparar un console.log() en el evento de click para ver si se dispara una vez o más veces.

Comment: @JonathanSchell te refieres a que haga doble click en lugar de uno?, el modal tiene la opción activada para que no se cierre que hago click fuera de el

Comment: Sí, intenta antes envíar un console log para ver si se está ejecutando 2 veces el evento, si tu modal se cierra cuando haces click fuera de él puede ser que estés habilitandolo en el primer click y cerrandolo al segundo (sin querer).

Comment: Descubrí que el sitio inicia con un evento click ya que apenas se muestra en la consola muestra el resultado del conlose.log(), pero al hacer click para que muestre el modal hace una especie de refresco de pagina y borra todo lo del console.log() y vuelve a iniciar como si entrara por primer vez, que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: qui esta lo que me muestra con el log https://imgur.com/a/JbVBX0y